# select from table with title in Realm

Tags: android, sqlite, t-sql, android-recyclerview, realm

I'm beginner in Real programming.I used Sqlite before and now i try to learn Realm.I found one tutorial and everything is perfect

> [this tutorial](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/realm-database-example)

I can show all my values in RecyclerView.But i have one question.How i can return all values from database where title equals for example hello and got i can show it in RecyclerView
This is java code

```
@Bind(R.id.edit_title) EditText mEditTitle;
@Bind(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Realm mRealm;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mRealm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edition, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<MyBook> books = mRealm.where(MyBook.class).equalTo("title", "Hello").findAll();

    mRealm.commitTransaction();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(mRealm.allObjects(MyBook.class)));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mRealm.close();
}

@OnClick(R.id.button_add)
public void onAddClick() {
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    MyBook book = mRealm.createObject(MyBook.class);
    book.setTitle(getTrimmedTitle());
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}

@OnClick(R.id.button_remove)
public void onRemoveClick() {
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    RealmResults<MyBook> books = mRealm.where(MyBook.class).equalTo("title", getTrimmedTitle()).findAll();
    if(!books.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = books.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            books.get(i).removeFromRealm();
        }
    }
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}

private String getTrimmedTitle() {
    return mEditTitle.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

if anyone knows solution please help me.
P.s as i said i'm beginner Realm programming and good tutorials or examples would be perfect for me
thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm works like any other database, make a query. 
This is for a Iterator, but you can have a List

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 Iterator all = (MyBook)realm.where(MyBook.class).equalTo("title", "hello").findAll().iterator ();
```

Where title is the name of your variable in MyBook class and hello is the name you are looking for

Comment: I wrote this code and it's work  RealmResults<MyBook> books = mRealm.where(MyBook.class).equalTo("title", "hello").findAll();
        mRealm.commitTransaction();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(books)); is it a correct solution ? @Dinorah Tovar

Comment: commitTransaction() is when you write to the data base. When you are making a consult you don't need it.